# Proof of Menelaus' theorem using barycentric coordinate

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I am studying barycentric coordinate. How do you prove the Menelaus' theorem using barycentric coordinate.

**My Attempt:**
Let $P,Q,R$ be points in $BC,CA,AB$ respectively
$A= (1,0,0)$
$B=(0,1,0)$
$C = (0,0,1)$
$P=(0,p,1-p)$
$Q = (1-q,0,q)$
$R = (r,1-r,0)$
$\frac{BP}{PC} \cdot \frac{CQ}{AQ} \cdot \frac{AR}{RB} = 1 \iff pqr=(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$
. I then used the area formula to determine the equation of $PR,RQ$. I don't know that to do next.

Comment: The points $P$, $Q$, $R$ will be collinear if the determinant of their barycentric coordinates vanish. Show that this condition is equivalent to Menelaus' theorem. (Be careful about signs.)

Comment: @Blue I got that it is equal to $pqr+(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$. What's wrong with my signs now?

Comment: Your determinant is correct, so setting that equal to zero, you get $(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)=-pqr$. That's Menelaus' theorem, so you're done. (Having $+pqr$ (and $+1$ in the product of ratios) is Ceva's theorem.)